# Append MATLAB output to a txt file containing text

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix of data in MATLAB, and I want to save it to a text file. I know I can use

```
save('data.txt','data','-ascii');
```

but I also have header information I want to include before the data that I'm currently using fprintf to add to the file. When I then use the save function it overwrites this and just leaves a file with only the data. How can I append the data below the header information?

Thanks

Comment: if you are using fprintf the 'printing' mode is determined by how you open the file with fopen. fopen('filename','w') overwrites, fopen('filename','a') appends

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer.

```
writematrix(data,'data.txt','WriteMode','append');
```